# Service Worker's fetch event Doesn't fire after service worker registration

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm new to Service Worker, I tried to write some code to learn how to use Service Worker in My Next.js Application but found some problems with fetch event handler, for some reason fetch event handler doesn't run when registering the service worker for the first time but when i just refresh the page the event handler works just fine and i don't know why , this my app's public folder structure:

```
/public
    /assets
    /icons
    manifest.json
    service-worker.js
    service-worker-registration.js
```

manifest.js:

```
{
  "name": "FakeHulu",
  "short_name": "FakeHulu",
  "description": "My Own version of Hulu",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/manifest-icon-192.maskable.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    }, ...

  ],
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "start_url": "/",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait"
}
```

service-worker-registration.js:

```
if("serviceWorker" in navigator){
    window.navigator.serviceWorker.register("/service-worker.js", { scope: '/' }).then(sw => console.log("serviceWorker Supported and register"))
}
```

service-worker.js:

```
self.addEventListener("install" , evt => {
    evt.waitUntil(caches.open("main_cache").then(cache => cache.addAll(["/", "/something"])));

    self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate" , evt => {
    console.log(evt);
    clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch" , evt => {
    console.log(evt);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On your fist load the order of operation is this:

1. Download the client page.
2. Find the the sw registration in the client page and download it.
3. Install the service worker.

Notice that there's no `fetch()` handler to run when your client and service worker are downloaded because the service worker hasn't been installed yet.

On reload the order is this:

1. Refresh the page.
2. The `Fetch()` handler in the existing service worker intercepts the request and decides whether to retrieve the requested resource from a local resource or from the network.

Comment: but calling clients.claim() inside activate event handler should override the default and allow the fetch event handler to run

Comment: But that call to `claim()` only occurs after the fetch that downloaded the service worker. The browser would need to replay the fetch, which would redownload the service worker, which would retrigger `claim()`, and on and on.

Comment: @StormyKnight so there is no way to install service worker before downloading client page? I'm trying to add Authorization headers for fetching images but it's failing on the first load or hard refresh. It works on refresh (I assume because page is already downloaded)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. There is no way to install a service worker before its client page. By design the service worker is a progressive enhancement of the client page, not the other way around.

Comment: Can you try: `evt.waitUntil(clients.claim());`?

Comment: @StormyKnight For me, `fetch()` event triggered if I am moving the service worker file in the root directory (`/`) of the project. Previously I was using that inside the `/src/` folder in my Single page (Vue + Vite) application.

Comment: That actually makes sense. The service worker needs to be in the root of the pages you're trying to control.